# Slurm job submisson script: assigning gpus to separate processes when asking for multiple nodes

Tags: gpu, slurm

I'm trying to submit a slurm job that requires 8 gpus. The cluster I am submitting to has 2 gpus per node and therefore I request 4 nodes.
I was wondering how can I construct my job submission script so that 32 processes are split amongst the 8 gpus (4 processes/gpu)?

I have tried something like the following but am not sure it is going to work as `echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES`gives 0,1 only

```
#SBATCH --nodes=4                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#SBATCH --ntasks 32                                                                                                                                                                                                
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task 1                                                                                                                                                                                          
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:2                                                                                                                                                                                               
#SBATCH --time 72:00:00                                                                                                                                                                                            
#SBATCH --mem=60G                                                                                                                                                                                                  

#...


n_drivers=4

export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0

for i in `seq 1 $n_drivers`; do \
 # run process
  done;

n_drivers=8


export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=1

for i in `seq 5 $n_drivers`; do \
 # run process
  done;


wait

export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=2

#... and so on up to 

export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=7



for i in `seq 29 $n_drivers`; do \
 # run process
  done;
```